# Changing an 8 character string in the form "yyyymmdd" into year, month, and day integer values

Tags: python, string

I am trying to write a function that converts an 8 character string of the form "yyyymmdd" into integer values of year, month, and day based on the string. The function parses a given string and returns integer year, month and day. I wrote the code for it, but I am having difficulties with returning the correct integer values in the right format. For example: y, m, d = parseDate("19700218") should return the integer values 1970 for y, 2 for m, and 18 for d.
My code is not correct, but I think that the start of it is correct:

```
def parseDate(datestr):
    datestr.split()
    datestr.strip()
    return datestr
```

y,m,d = parseDate("19700218")

I hope that this is just an easy fix.

Comment: Do you know what `split`  and `strip` do?

Comment: If you want your function to provide three values, you should also return three values and calculate them before. You just return the string which is given to the function unchanged.

Comment: One straightforward way would be to index, as:
  date = '19700218'
  year = date[0:4]
  etc

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and get values from parsed date/datetime object.

This is out of the box, flexible and extendable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
def parse_date(string_date):
    year = int(string_date[0:4])
    month = int(string_date[4:6])
    day = int(string_date[6:8])
    return year, month, day

year, month, day = parse_date(date)
```

Test Code

```
date = '19901131'

def parse_date(string_date):
    year = int(string_date[0:4])
    month = int(string_date[4:6])
    day = int(string_date[6:8])
    return year, month, day

year, month, day = parse_date(date)

print(year)
print(month)
print(day)
```

Output

```
1990
11
31
```

Since we are converting to int, leading 0s will be dropped. Let me know if u want to include a format that includes leadings 0s

Comment: This can all be simplified to `year, month, day = map(int, (string_date[:4], string_date[4:6], string_date[6:]))`.

Comment: True but the OP was using a function in his question. I thought it best to provide an answer in the same format. Plus I believe it is a bit more clear about what is happening rather than condense it all down to one line.

Comment: I think the function definition is closer to what OP wanted, too. However, I don't understand why you didn't include the cast to `int` into the function - what does it do outside afterwards?

Comment: Funny you say that, I made my edit right before you commented that to for that reason.

Comment: I only intended to demonstrate the logic behind my suggestion. This can naturally be encompassed in a function. It's certainly clear and pythonic, though one may need to explain to a beginner with `map()` does. I mentioned it because this can be a natural follow up to your answer for conciseness.

Comment: I do like your way much better Reti. I think its worth an answer on this question, especially for beginner programmer to understand how to write things more pythonic.

Comment: :) _pythonic_ - iirc particularly `map` et.al. are quite debatable regarding their _pythonicness_... How about a simple LC: `year, month, day = [int(s) for s in (string_date[:4], string_date[4:6], string_date[6:])]`

Answer (score 1):

Code

```
s = "19700218"
y = s[0:4]
m = s[5:6]
d = s[6:8]
```

Output

```
y=1970
m=02
d=18
```

Hope it helps.